# How to solve SplitsrcTargetPreparation exception in Oracle weblogic server?

Tags: eclipse, oracle, jakarta-ee, webserver, ear

I am trying to run a simple Restful web service example on oracle weblogic server . but i am getting this issue while run the project on server. Publishing to Oracle Weblogic server at localhost has encountered a problem.Runtime exception occurred in publish task 'SplitsrcTargetPreparation'.
Have a look on screen sort.
What i have to do ?
[image]

Comment: Did u solve the issue?

Answer (score 9):

None of the other answers solved my problem, but I finally found a solution. I'm not claiming that this is the best or only way of resolving this issue, but it worked for me. Hope it helps others.

Open the **Properties** of your WebLogic server instance in Eclipse. Select **Publishing**. Set the publishing mode to "*Publish as an exploded archive*". You will no longer get a split source error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the following.

1. Maven version – If you have imported as a maven project then make
   sure that maven version is compatible to the java version you are
   using.
2. Makes sure that you are using the java from the Middleware
       which is comes bundled with weblogic.
3. New domain – Corrupt domain
       may also cause this. Create a new domain

Comment: It worked for me when I changed the JRE version to the one coupled with Eclipse. Thank you user129856 for the answer.